# If $A^2+A=0$,then $\lambda=1$ cannot be an eigenvalue of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

> Prove the following statement:
>
> If $A^2+A=0$,then $\lambda=1$ cannot be an eigenvalue of A.

I've been struggling on this question for a couple of hours and don't know how to approach it.

Comment: In fact the eigenvalues of $A$ _must_ be a subset of $\{-1,0\}$. (There is nothing special about $\lambda=1$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there were an eigenvector $v$ of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$, we'd have

$$(A^2 + A)v = A A v + Av = Av + v = v + v = 2v$$

On the other hand,

$$(A^2 + A)v = 0v = 0$$

Comment: That's not really a hint, it's a full solution.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v$.  What is $(A^2+A)v$?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one thing you can do with an eigenvalue $\lambda$ for a matrix $A$ without having to delve into the complicated or subtle: say that there exists an eigenvector $v$ for $\lambda$

And there is essentially only one thing you can know about $v$:

$$ Av = \lambda v$$

Thus, unless you want to start searching for more complicated ways to start this problem, there is pretty much only one thing you can do with the claim "1 is an eigenvalue": assert the existence of an eigenvector $v$, and multiply things by $v$ and see if you can make use of the equation $Av = v$.

$A^2 + A = 0$ is important in this problem. It's essentially the only "interesting" object you've been presented with. Thus, before we try inventing our own things to multiply by $v$, we should try multiplying *this* by $v$ to see what happens.

- $ (A^2 + A)v = 0v $
- $ A(Av) + Av = 0$
- $ Av + v = 0$
- $v + v = 0$
- $2v = 0$
- $v = 0$

Thus, we tried doing just about the only thing we can do without trying to be clever or complicated, and we were rewarded with a very useful piece of information: if $v$ is an eigenvector for $1$, then $v=0$.

This contradicts the fact that eigenvectors are nonzero. Thus, the claim "1 is an eigenvector" leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this may be a solution as well...

$A^2+A=0$

$A(A+I_n)=0$

$\therefore$ $A=[0]$  or  $A=-I_n$

Since $A=0$ and $A=-I_n$ are both diagonal matrices, the possible eigenvalues for $A$ are simply the entries of the diagonal.

$\therefore$ the possible eigenvalues of $A$ are:

$\lambda=0$, and $\lambda=-1$

Therefore, it is not possible for $\lambda=1$ to be an eigenvalue of $A$

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work because two nonzero matrices can multiply to make zero.  For example, the $2\times 2$ matrix with a $1$ in the top right corner and zeroes elsewhere squares to make zero.

Comment: You have "proved" that $A$ must be either the zero matrix or the negative of the identity matrix. But this matrix, $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, satisfies $A^2+A=0$ and is neither of those things. As @Aaron says, just because $AB=0$ with matrices, it does not imply that one of $A$ or $B$ equals $0$.

Comment: However you may be interested to know that $A$'s eigenvalues must indeed be a subset of $\{-1,0\}$. We just have to bypass your argument that uses matrix factorization. Instead, if $\vec{x}$ is an eigenvector for $A$, then $\lambda^2\vec{x}+\lambda\vec{x}=\vec{0}$, which implies $\lambda^2+\lambda=0$. This _real_ polynomial can be factored and conclusions may be drawn from the factors.

Comment: Please, remove this answer: it's completely wrong.